# Debugging another programmers library

Tags: c++, netbeans

I have some other coders c++ library which contains source file, makefile etc. I am interested in understanding this library. i.e. what it does(it is poorly documented), how it does, etc.
One way I have is to include this as a library in my code. But I dont want that as I want to debug the code using netbeans(in order to understand the code flow).

Is there some way by which I may debug the library in order to understand it.

Now when I just merely copy paste the other programs code into my netbeans project. It gives me makefile problems. Is there some other way out?

Also the other programmers library has a lot of errors.

Comment: You should compile the library in debug mode (`-g` compiler flag for most compilers) and link your program against that build. Depending on the debugger and IDE, you can simply step into the library's code as if it was just own code of your program. (I successfully do so with g++, gdb in the QtCreator IDE. I don't know how Netbeans behaves in this point, but I think it should work as most of the work is done by the (external) debugger itself.)

Comment: Have you tried compiling the library with debug info enabled?

Comment: @leemes I am using netbeans as the IDE

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am not getting how to do it within netbeans

Comment: Personal opinion: You should definitively try to fix the bugs in cooperation with the library programmer if he is willing to do so, not only by yourself.

Comment: @leemes The library programmer has left the organization. And the library is the copyright of the company

Comment: Try in the menu: `Project Properties -> Build -> C++ Compiler -> Additional Option` Add the compiler option `-g` if not already present. Note: This step has to be done *for the library* as well as *for the project using it*. Also, you have to recompile both projects completely.

Comment: @leemes When I use this approach it just helps me in stepping through the .h files and not .c files..but i really want to traverse through .c files